# How to replicate float:left type of effect for height of window instead?

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I am trying to do something similar to float:left. For float:left, if you set a bunch of divs with this style property, it will position itself according to the width of window. When the window gets too narrow, it will become one column, and when we have large window, it will expand to multiple columns and so forth.

I want to do something similar but I want it to work like a vertical float. So if I have 5 items and the browser's window height can only contain 4 in one column, the extra div should position itself to the 2nd column. In simple terms, if I have a long list of divs, they should be listed in columns depending on the height of window.

Is there a way to do this with div and css or jquery ui?

Comment: Take a look at http://masonry.desandro.com

Comment: What browsers are you trying to support for this (how backwards compatible)?

Comment: @ScottS, IE8, Firefox and Chrome would be preferred. But if IE is too much to ask, any lib that may offer an easy solution would be okay.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible with CSS alone. Your best bet is something like masonry:

http://masonry.desandro.com/

(or for snazzy filtering and stuffs isotope, which is powered by masonry: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I'll give it a upvote for introducting me to these cool libraries. But they seem to be a more clever version of float with packing/gap filling abilities. So the examples still populate divs horizontally on the page, I'll give it a shot since it says it is the flip-side of float, hopefully it works.

Comment: You could also look into media queries and the CSS3 flexbox, however, that is very experimental and only works in webkit at the moment. Here's a blog post with some info anyway: http://blog.isotoma.com/2010/08/css3-flexbox/